# Vue-JS Object get API is not filling select with array of objects

Tags: vue.js

Vue-JS Object get API is not filling select with array of objects.

Here's my data:

```
data() {
return {
  elementsReport: [],
  types: [],
  drivers: [],
  disabledCard: [],
  driver: '',
  type: '',
  initialDate: '',
  finalDate: '',
};
```

},

Here's my "mounted":

```
mounted() {
this.getListDriversAPI();
this.getReportTypesAPI();
```

},

Here's my function api:

```
async getListDriversAPI() {
  const _this = this;
  await axios
    .get("/web-api/drivers/" + _this.companie_id)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      _this.drivers = data; // Is Array
      console.log(_this.drivers);
    });
},
```

Here's my select:

```
              <select
                v-model="driver"
                class="form-control"
                data-size="5"
                data-live-search="true"
                data-width="100%"
                name="driver"
                required
                id="driver"
              >
                <option disabled value="0">Escolha uma opção</option>
                <option v-for="driver in drivers" :value="driver.id">{{driver.name}}</option>
              </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you should be using `await` with `.then()`

Maybe try this:

```js
async getListDriversAPI() {
  const response = await axios
    .get("/web-api/drivers/" + _this.companie_id);
  this.drivers = response.data;
  console.log(this.drivers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Promise:

```js
getListDriversAPI() {
  axios.get(`/web-api/drivers/${this.companie_id}`)
    .then(data => {
      this.drivers = data;
      console.log(this.drivers);
    });
}
```

Using async/await:

```js
async getListDriversAPI() {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`/web-api/drivers/${this.companie_id}`)
  this.drivers = data;
  console.log(this.drivers);
}
```